# How to create a very restricted user account into windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, user-accounts

I want to create an account on my computer for my son but I want it to be very limited so he can only run some of the applications, not to install or download anything even in his profile, maybe limit his browsing capabilities ....

Is it possible with Windows 10? I don't like the image approach as I will need to maintain this separate image, I'm looking for a way of dealing with this based on permissions if possible.

Comment: Parental Controls will do a lot of what you want. Start by reading [The Best Windows 10 Parental Control Tools](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-10-parental-control-tools/) and [Check Out The New Windows 10 Parental Control Options](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/check-new-windows-10-parental-control-options/). Come back if you have specific questions .As it stands this question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

- Open Windows settings and select Accounts.
- Windows 10's Setting Menu with Accounts highlighted Select Family &
  Other People from the left-hand menu.
- Windows 10's Setting Menu with Family and other people highlighted
  Click on Add a Family Member.
- Windows 10's Family and other people Menu with add a family member
  highlighted Select Add a Child.
- Windows 10's Add a family member Menu with add a child highlighted
  “Add a Child" is selected by default. Enter the email address of
  their Microsoft Account below if you have it. (Remember that you’ll
  need access to their email to confirm they are your child.) If your
  child already has a Microsoft account, click through the remainder of
  this dialog and skip to Step 11. If not, click “The person I want to
  add doesn’t have an email address” and we’ll walk you through
  creating one for them.
- Create a Microsoft account if you don’t already have one.
- Windows 10's Lets create an account pop up If you need to create a
  Microsoft Account, fill in your child’s email address (or one you
  create for this purpose) and demographic information here. Write down
  the password you choose for them and keep it safe, in case you need
  to modify their account settings later.
- Uncheck these two boxes before continuing, to minimize junk mail.
- Windows 10's See what is most relevant pop up Microsoft will then
  prompt you to sign in to your own account.
- Windows 10's please reenter your password pop up You’ll have to sign
  in here with your own Microsoft password in order to confirm it’s
  you. This is to prevent unauthorized users (or curious toddlers) from
  making account changes if you’ve left your system unattended.
- Confirm that your child can use the account to access online
  services.

Check: https://www.netnanny.com/blog/how-to-set-parental-controls-for-windows-10/ For additional details.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to internal controls that Windows 10 offers (described by helper), there are quite a few third-party applications that you can use.

One of them is Kaspersky Safe Kids. It has got a free version as well. The paid version gives you activity reports e.g. how many hours, what sites, which applications, etc. and can be used on multiple devices including smartphones. I found that it is especially useful for personal computers running Windows, and for android devices, but not so much for iPhone/iPad. Overall, I found Kaspersky Free good enough for my needs, but it is not as polished or as responsive as I would like it to be. (https://www.kaspersky.com/safe-kids)

Another such application is Norton Family but I don't have any personal experience with it.